# How to concat 2 cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have it in my cells A5:

```
A:E
```

and in my cell B6, I have it :

```
3
```

I try to say in other cells :

```
A3:E3
```

to select all row from A3 to E3

I tried to use Concat with excel but it put me error
thanks for reading me

Comment: If I understand your question, try `INDIRECT` and maybe `INDEX` too.

Comment: hello, ty for answering, no indirect and index are not usefull here because I'm always in my same sheet tab

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. INDIRECT and INDEX  work whether you're referring to the same sheet or another.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, it works with `INDIRECT` or `INDEX` Function, you have mentioned correctly, there is no doubt at all!

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Is this what you are trying to achieve, as [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) Sir, rightly mentioned you need `INDIRECT` Function

```
=INDIRECT(LEFT(A5)&B6&":"&RIGHT(A5)&B6)
```

If you dont want to use `INDIRECT` Function as just show as `A3:E3`, then simply,

```
=LEFT(A5)&B6&":"&RIGHT(A5)&B6
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering !  It doesn't work for me, it put me #NAME?       So I did this :  =CONCAT(F9;$B$19&":"&G9;$B$20)

Comment: @fred `#NAME?` error in `Excel` occurs when you incorrectly type the range name, refer to a deleted range name, or forget to put quotation marks around a text string in a formula. And the top reason why the` #NAME?` error appears in the formula is because there is a typo in the formula name this is as documented in `Microsoft`.

Comment: @fred you may try using the `TEXTJOIN` function as well --> `=TEXTJOIN(":",,LEFT(A5)&B6,RIGHT(A5)&B6)`

Comment: Or `=INDEX(INDIRECT(A5),B6,)`

Comment: @P.b Sir, thank you i was tryin this but wasn't able to make out, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

### An INDEX/INDIRECT Combination

- This looks like the most 'elegant' solution to me:

  ```
  INDEX(INDIRECT($A$5),$B$6,) ' short for INDEX(INDIRECT($A$5),$B$6,0)
  ```
- Credits should also go to **P.b**, who figured it out earlier in the comments.
- It took me a while since I started with the wrong formula `INDEX(INDIRECT($A$5),$B$6)` ignoring the column argument.
- Only when I realized that `=COLUMNS(INDIRECT($A$5))` returned `5`, I got back to `INDEX` and figured it out.
- Here are a few examples of how you can utilize it:

  ```
  =COUNT(INDEX(INDIRECT($A$5),$B$6,))
  =SUM(INDEX(INDIRECT($A$5),$B$6,))
  =AVERAGE(INDEX(INDIRECT($A$5),$B$6,))
  ```

Comment: Thank You Sir, for the whole explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1)-1)&A2&RIGHT(A1;FIND(":";A1))&A2
```

A2 contains "3", A1 contains "A:E"